# Is it $|y| = \arccos(\frac{e^{-x}}{2})$ the curve described by $h(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i2\pi\frac{n}{t}}}{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, analytic-number-theory

Let
$$ h(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i2\pi\frac{n}{t}}}{n} $$

A few facts and conjectures that I consider interesting about $h$:

- $h$ gathers well-known results and appears to generalize them:

  - $h(1)$ is the harmonic series. It diverges;
  - $h(2)$ is the alternating harmonic series, with a minus sign. It converges to $-\log{2}$;
  - $h(6)$ appears to converge to $i\frac{\pi}{3}$
- $h$ has functional equations:

  - for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $ h(t) = h(\frac{t}{kt+1}) $;
  - for any $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q} - \{ 0 \} $, $ h(\frac{p}{q}) = h(\frac{p}{q \mod p})$;

My question is: is the following conjecture true? "The image of $h$ is the curve with equation $ |y| = \arccos(\frac{e^{-x}}{2}) $", where $x$ is the real part, $y$ the imaginary part.

Comment: What does "image of the domain of definition of $h$" mean? Also, should the sum start from $n = 1$?

Comment: I meant the codomain. And yes, the sum starts from n = 1, sorry. I edited the question.

Comment: Not the codomain either; the image.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but I genuinely don't even know what that means. Does that mean "where $h$ is defined"?

Comment: Yes, the image of $h$ is the set of all $h(t)$ when $t$ describes the domain of definition of $h$.

Comment: For real $t$, we have $ x+iy = h(t) = -\log(1 - e^{2\pi i/t}) $. Now by noting that your equation is equivalent to $$ \operatorname{Re}(e^{h(t)})=e^x \cos(y)=\frac{1}{2}, $$ the question boils down to checking $$\operatorname{Re}\biggl(\frac{1}{1-e^{2\pi i/t}}\biggr) = \frac{1}{2}, $$ which is indeed easy to verify.

Comment: Thank you very much.